# C# count paragraphs in div from a website's html source code

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

Using **Html Agility Pack** i have been trying to count the number of paragraphs tags in each div tag and get the div id and class(if they exist) of the one that has the most paragraphs but i'm having trouble with the syntax.

My code looks like this:

```
// HtmlDocument is stored in doc
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection div = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div");

    foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode divNode in div)
    {
        var x = divNode.DescendantNodes("p").Count; // doesn't actually work
        // x should also be stored in a list
    }
```

If anyone could point me to right direction or provide me with examples, it would really help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this way :

```
//get the maximum number of paragraph
int maxNumberOfParagraph = 
            doc.DocumentNode
               .SelectNodes("//div[.//p]")
               .Max(o => o.SelectNodes(".//p").Count);

//get divs having number of containing paragraph equals maxNumberOfParagraph 
var divs = doc.DocumentNode
              .SelectNodes("//div[.//p]")
              .Where(o => o.SelectNodes(".//p").Count == maxNumberOfParagraph);
```

Comment: Let's say we have 5 divs, each of them containing 3 paragraphs. The total would be 15 paragraphs. Then we search for a div which has 15 paragraphs which results in none, right? It doesn't seem to me like it will work but thanks anyway.

Comment: No. In that case, `maxNumberOfparagraph` will be 3, and `divs` will contain all those 5 divs. Try it out.

Comment: Not exactly what i wanted, but definately helped me reach my goal. Thanks!